# Why is Game Theory used to explain implementations of 3GPP D2D communication?

Tags: game-theory, communication-protocols

My question is about D2D as it relates to 3GPP (release 13+, I believe).  All I have read on the subject uses Game Theory as a mechanism to explain usage.  Why would authors use Game Theory for explaining D2D with 3GPP (5G, LTE) communication?  Have telephony companies had to do the same with 3G and 4G for some reason?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. I realize you expect an answer from specialists. But this is intended for and read by a number of people with varying competence. It would be nice to make your question more understandable even by computer scientist that are not in this area, for example by explaining the acronyms, or including links to web pages that explain them. Why do you ask this question? Would you have a different suggestion?